# Android Download Manager - Find if a particular download is incomplete

Tags: android, download

I am using Android Download Manager to download my files in target directories.

```
public static void downloadUsingADM(String url, String targetRelDirPath, String fileName){
        android.app.DownloadManager.Request request = new android.app.DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(targetRelDirPath, fileName);
        PlayerUtils.downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    }
```

Upon downloading, the file comes to the target directory path. But, how do I find if a particular download is complete/incomplete ?

Answer (score 0):

With the [DownloadManager.Query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#query(android.app.DownloadManager.Query)) function you can retrieve status of (your) downloads.

> Query the download manager about downloads that have been requested.
>
> RETURN: a Cursor over the result set of downloads, with columns consisting of all the COLUMN_* constants.

Possible values of COLUMN_STATUS:

```
STATUS_FAILED
STATUS_PAUSED
STATUS_PENDING
STATUS_RUNNING
STATUS_SUCCESSFUL
```

Possible values of `COLUMN_REASON`:

```
ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME
ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND
ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS
ERROR_FILE_ERROR
ERROR_HTTP_DATA_ERROR
ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE
ERROR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
ERROR_UNHANDLED_HTTP_CODE
PAUSED_QUEUED_FOR_WIFI
PAUSED_UNKNOWN
PAUSED_WAITING_FOR_NETWORK
PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY
```